# is it possible to get a variable out of a function, into another function, if the first one doesn't trigger by the second one?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
def NewNote(x, y):
    print("something")
    text = input()
    return (text)

def Delete(x, y):
    text = GetText()
    pen.write(text, align="left", font=("arial", TextSize))
    print(text)

**text = BlackSquare.onrelease(NewNote)**
**text = VerLine.onrelease(NewNote)**
**text = HorzLine.onrelease(NewNote)**
color = turtle.onscreenclick(settings)
WhiteeraserSquare.onrelease(Delete)
BlackeraserSquare.onrelease(Delete)

def GetText():
    textA = text
    return textA
```

< so basically the NewNote function gets triggered by one of the starred triggers, takes an input from the user, and from there i want to get that input to the delete function. so i tried to return it to the trigger, save it again as a variable, than put it into another function that would send it back up to the
delete function, but i clearly don't understand how the whole **return** thing works, because the delete function keeps printing "none".

(i am using the Turtle graphics module, so.. the triggers, and the pen.write are from there).

ps: this is my first time asking a question in stack overflow, so if i did something wrong, forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding turtle event handlers and need to (re)read about them:

```
def NewNote(x, y):
    print("something")
    text = input()
    return (text)

text = BlackSquare.onrelease(NewNote)
```

The `onrelease()` method doesn't return anything (returns `None`) so assigning its result into the `text` variable does nothing.

The `NewNote()` event handler's caller doesn't care about its return value so the `return (text)` is basically ignored.

Here's a simple example that I hope will help you understand how these functions are used.  It puts up two turtle buttons, a green and red square.  Click on the green one and it will prompt you for input and write in the center of the screen.  Click on the red one and it will erase that text:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def delete_text(x, y):
    pen.clear()

def write_text(x, y):
    text = screen.textinput("Text Input", "Enter some text")
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(text, align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'))

screen = Screen()

write = Turtle()
write.shape('square')
write.color('green')
write.penup()
write.onrelease(write_text)
write.backward(200)

erase = Turtle()
erase.shape('square')
erase.color('red')
erase.penup()
erase.onrelease(delete_text)
erase.forward(200)

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()

screen.mainloop()
```

To pass information between `write_text()` and `delete_text()` requires some sort of global entity through which to pass this information.  It can be as simple as a global variable or something more complex like an object that's passed as an extra argument to the handers via a `lambda` expression.

Comment: thanks, but the reason i tried to move the `text` variable is because i wanted to be able to delete just the last text that has been Written on the screen. and since thare is no such function, i figared that if i will be able to get the `text`variable to the delete function, than i would be able to print it on the screen again on the same coordinates, but in white, that would be just like deleting it. but now i know that its not possible without the global thing, any way.. thanks